# I am trying to scrape website, but I encountered a problem. When I try to scrape data, it looks like the html differs from what I see on

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape website, but I encountered a problem. When I try to scrape data, it looks like the html differs from what I see on clicking the inspect option. I am trying to scrape "https://bri.co.id/en/lokasi" site to obtain the branch name and address for all the branches of the bank.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/manisha.rawat/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")

URL = 'https://bri.co.id/en/lokasi'

driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

driver.quit()

print(soup.find('div',class_="address"))
```

The code prints just one address. I require all the addresses. Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach using python - [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the API URL which is created using, query string parameters, headers, form data and its dynamic parameters(all in caps) and do POST request.
2. Form data is dynamic you can pass any valid value in the params and the data will be created for you every time you want to fetch something from the site.(!Important do not change value of Page_No parameter).
3. After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
4. Finally it will iterate all over the list of addresses fetched in each iteration or page for ex:- Address, Name, Agent Code, Map URL, Phone etc, you can modify these attributes as per your need.

   ```
   def scrape_addresses():

     url = "https://bri.co.id/en/lokasi" # API URL

     querystring = {"p_p_id":"location_display_ortlet","p_p_lifecycle":"2",
              "p_p_state":"normal","p_p_mode":"view",
              "p_p_resource_id":"/location/ui/search",
              "p_p_cacheability":"cacheLevelPage"}  # API URL query string parameters !Important to add
     headers = {
          'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          'cache-control': "no-cache"
               }    # headers and type !Important to add
     #Parameters to create form data (Change as per your need except Page_No parameter)
     PAGE_NO = 1
     LOCATION_TYPE = ''
     PROVINCE = ''
     SERVICE = ''

     while True:
         print('Creating new form data for page no : ' + str(PAGE_NO))
         # Request payload or form-data !Important to add
         payload = '_location_display_ortlet_page=' + str(PAGE_NO) + 
                  '&_location_display_ortlet_locationType=' + LOCATION_TYPE + 
                  '&_location_display_ortlet_province=' + PROVINCE + 
                  '&_location_display_ortlet_service=' + SERVICE

         # POST request with provided URL
         response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, 
                      params=querystring,verify = False)

         print('Created new form data going to fetch data...')

         result = json.loads(response.text) #Parse result using JSON loads

         if len(result) == 0:
            break
         else:
            extracted_data = result['data']
            for data in extracted_data:
                print('-' * 100)
                print('Fetching data for : ' , data['name'])
                print('Address : ', data['address'])
                print('Agent Code : ',data['agentCode'])
                print('ID : ', data['id'])
                print('Latitude : ',data['latitude'])
                print('Longitude : ',data['longitude'])
                print('Name : ',data['name'])
                print('Opening Hours : ',data['openingHours'])
                print('Phone : ', data['phone'])
                print('Service Offered : ',data['serviceOffered'])
                print('Type : ',data['type'])
                print('Maps URL : ',data['urlMaps'])
                print('-' * 100)
       PAGE_NO += 1 #increment page number after each iteration to scrap more data
    scrape_addresses()
   ```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain how to obtain the API url query string parameter? I tried right clicking, inspect and network option,  but can't figure out how to proceed?

Comment: Just open network tab and click on XHR option which will filter out and display all the AJAX calls. I would suggest after clicking on XHR hit refresh and then check each and every AJAX call > preview tab of API Calls. In preview tab just search for data which you are looking for but there is no guarantee that you will get data in every website. All the best..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`find` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) is pretty clear: it only gives you the first result.

To get all the results of the filter, use [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)